# Django: Querying of interlinked modals ... how best to achieve a prefetch or select related?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following two modals, the notion of a Waiver:

```
class Waiver(
        BaseModels.AbstractUUIDModel,
        BaseModels.AbstractTimestampedModel,
    ):


    ...
```

And the notion of a CheckIn:

```
class CheckIn(
        BaseModels.AbstractUUIDModel,
        BaseModels.AbstractTimestampedModel,
    ):

    waiver = models.ForeignKey('Waivers.Waiver', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Essentially, a `CheckIn` is linked to a `Waiver`.

Within a viewset, I would like to return a QuerySet of `Waivers`, with the associated `CheckIns` linked.

I have tried to produce the following to get a `.values()` list of the queryset.

```
Waiver.objects.filter(
    void_type='0'
).filter(
    performance_datetime__year=date.year,
    performance_datetime__month=date.month,
    performance_datetime__day=date.day
).exclude(
    code='SPECTATOR'
).prefetch_related(
    'checkin_set'
).order_by(
    'performance_datetime'
).values()
```

However, this doesn't seem to be prefetching the CheckIns...am I missing something here?

Comment: if you want `prefetch_related`, don't use a `values()` queryset (prefetched related objects are stored on a cache on the main model _instances_, and a `values()` queryset yields dicts, not model instances).